# Curious about definition of well-ordered set

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

We know that the definition of a well-ordered set guarantees the existence of least element in every non-empty subset of a set.

This isn't a creative or good question, but I am just wondering why it using the existence of least element but not the greatest element or even both, just partially the least element. Anyone shed a bit light would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

It's just more natural that way, because it means that the smallest infinite well-ordered set is isomorphic to the natural numbers. If you changed the definition so that every subset had a greatest element, then you would get the negative integers instead. This is workable, I suppose, but why not do it the obvious way?

And if every subset of an ordered set $X$ had a least element *and* a greatest element, then $X$ would have to be finite, because a well-ordering (in the conventional sense) of an infinite set $X$ induces an obvious order-preserving bijection between the natural numbers and an initial segment of $X$ (and the natural numbers have no greatest element).

Answer (score 4):

About greatest element, well ordering comes to generalize in a sense the natural number, which has no maximum, so it makes sense to take least element.

In addition, it makes sense when looking on well founded sets, a well founded set is a set where when order by $∈$ it has a minimal element(not minimum, it need not be unique), that means, if $A$ is non empty well founded set, then there exists an element $a∈A$ such that $a\cap A=\emptyset$. Well founded sets by $∈$ have the property that $A∉A$.

Well ordered set by $∈$ are just like well founded but with the property that the minimal element is unique.

If you change it to maximal element, we get that well founded(by $∈$) sets will have the property that there exists $a∈A$ such that $a$ is not in any other $b∈A$.

A set, $A$, being well founded(by $∈$) implies there is no sequence $x_i$ such that $x_0∋x_1∋\cdots∋x_n\cdots$ where all $x_i$ are in $A$, if you replace it to maximal element it will say that you have no sequence $x_i$ such that $x_0∈x_1∈\cdots∈x_n∈\cdots$ with $x_i∈A$ for all $i$, but by the axiom of infinity, $ω$(the set of natural numbers) exists and it is such that $0∈1\in\cdots$ and all of those are in $ω$.

So it doesn't make sense to change it to greatest element.

Comment: Really appreciate for your help, but I don't get your analogy here " If you change it to maximal element, we get that well founded(by $∈$) sets will have the property that there exists $a∈A$ such that $a∩A$ is not in any other $b∈A$, but it does not prevent $A∉A$.

Comment: well-founded only assert there is no element could go infinitely "deep" in the set, doesn't really matter with the property of that element, so how do you come up with there exists $a\in A$ is not in any other $b\in A$.

Comment: @LawrenceGuo well founded set is about having a minimal element, which implies having infinite descending sequence (assuming the necessary stuff, the implications is also true for the other direction). So when you replace minimal to maximal you get that there is no infinite increasing sequence.

Comment: Thank you so much